# TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined (Making a ban command)

Tags: javascript, foreach

So I have been having this problem and I have been trying to fix it I can't find out what is wrong. I looked everywhere but people had a similar problem I tried it yet it failed. Here is my coding any help would be grateful.

Here is my original

```js
this.client.guilds.forEach(m => {
  m.ban(argUser.id, `"${reason}" - ${msgObject.author.tag}`);
});
```

So I even added a cache yet it still didn't work.

```js
this.client.guilds.cahce.forEach(m => {
  m.ban(argUser.id, `"${reason}" - ${msgObject.author.tag}`);
});
```

Here is more context

```
  async run(msgObject, { argUser, reason }) {
    
    if(argUser.id == 360751308652937217) {
      msgObject.reply(
        "Okay, this is a very dangerous situation. This action shall be done with no approval."
      );
      this.client.guilds.cache.forEach(m => {
       m.ban(argUser.id, `"${reason}" - ${msgObject.author.tag}`);
     });
     msgObject.channel.send(
       `Banned ${argUser.tag} in all the servers :triumph::relieved:! All done!`
     );
      return;
    }
```

Comment: You have a typo, `cahce` should be `cache`

Comment: your forEach method must be invoked on a list/array. are you sure this.client.quilds is a non-empty array?

Comment: @NickParsons Yeah, thanks for catching that but still seems to not work.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? And what does `this.client.guilds` look like? If you can provide those details, please.

Comment: @MikeW Sure, I edited my main question, go take a look! Thanks.

Comment: "Cannot read property forEach of undefined" means that `this.client.guilds` is undefined. Try to `console.log(...)` it and work backwards.

Comment: So pretty much this command bans the person from every discord the bot is in. It worked at one point but can't figure it out now.